# Selenium select a text in a not select input

Tags: selenium

How to select an element in this web element :

[image]

this input is a text type and not a select option !!!

Comment: Which language do you use? Also, provide an HTML code of the page or the link to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type some characters (or all/none of them) in that input box
2. Wait until the options appear
3. Take the identifier (id/XPath/class/CSS/etc.) of that element (option) (maybe it is a `div`)

   - F12 in Chrome > click on the magnifier > click on the option
   - F12 in Firefox/Internet Explorer > click on the arrow > click on the option
4. Click on that elements / take its content